# What is the proper syntax for PostgreSQL stored procedures (functions)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'm trying to write two types of stored procedures in PostgreSQL. From what I understand Postgre only has functions. I was wondering if someone can take a look at my code and offer pointers. Also, I'm am not familiar whether with the spacing/new lines of commands.

**The first function needs to take input from user and add it onto a table.**
Suppose we have a table name "Car" with attributes "model" and "year".
Will this be a correct stored function to add a new car to the table?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
    addto_car(model IN Car.model%type, year IN Car.year%type)
RETURNS
    void
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Car VALUES(model, year);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; (#Is this correct? I'm using postgresql 9)
```

---------- Work in Progress code
**Function 1**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
    addto_car(In model Car.model%type, IN year Car.year%type)
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Car VALUES(model, year);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This now works! (inserts values model and year into Car).

Comment: your quotes don't agree.  You start with `&&` and end with `$$`.  I'm pretty sure `&&` is an invalid quote delimiter to begin with; you should start and end your function body with `$$` or `$SOMETHING$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Official Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createfunction.html)

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] FUNCTION
    name ( [ [ argmode ] [ argname ] argtype [ { DEFAULT | = } default_expr ] [, ...] ] )
    [ RETURNS rettype
      | RETURNS TABLE ( column_name column_type [, ...] ) ]
  { LANGUAGE lang_name
    | WINDOW
    | IMMUTABLE | STABLE | VOLATILE
    | CALLED ON NULL INPUT | RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT | STRICT
    | [ EXTERNAL ] SECURITY INVOKER | [ EXTERNAL ] SECURITY DEFINER
    | COST execution_cost
    | ROWS result_rows
    | SET configuration_parameter { TO value | = value | FROM CURRENT }
    | AS 'definition'
    | AS 'obj_file', 'link_symbol'
  } ...
    [ WITH ( attribute [, ...] ) ]
```

You will find your answer there and, maybe, learn two or three useful things on the process.

You might be particularly interested in the `RETURNS TABLE` construct.

Comment: Hmm I'm having difficulty understanding all of the commands. Taking a look at my first function, for 'argtype' should I put 'IN' since I want to input values entered by user into the database?

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUCTION
    addto_car(IN model Car.model%type, IN year Car.year%type)
RETURNS
    void
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Car VALUES(model, year);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

Comment: I don't necessarily want it to return the table, I just want it to insert the new tuple so I'm not sure if I should use "RETURN TABLE" or "RETURN VOID"

Comment: Don't even use `RETURN` then. If you have problem figuring out the doc (that's understandable), take a look at the examples. Some of them don't even have the `RETURN` clause.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm going to make a new version so to show a 'work in progress' version of my code.

Comment: OK I understand how to do function 1. For function 2 can I use `RETURNS record`?